# UITableView inside UIView - data loads only when scrolling cells outside uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem using a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`:
When I start the app the `UITableView` is shown, but the data from _opponents isn't shown. 
When I start scrolling the first cell outside the `UITableView`, now this cell gets updated. 
Also, when I trigger [_topponents reloaddata] manually, the whole `UITableView` shows the correct data.

What do I have to add or change, so that the data is shown from the beginning?

`dataSource` and `delegate` are both connected with the class in the storyboard

Here is my code:
viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  myappdel = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  self.title = @"New Match";
  _lopponent.text = _opponent;

  opponents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableDictionary *opponent = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [opponent setObject:@"opponent A" forKey:@"name"];
  [opponent setObject:@"xx matches | xx wins || xx losts" forKey:@"stats"];
  [opponent setObject:@"Krems" forKey:@"location"];

  NSMutableDictionary *opponent2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [opponent2 setObject:@"opponent B" forKey:@"name"];
  [opponent2 setObject:@"yy matches | yy wins || yy losts" forKey:@"stats"];
  [opponent2 setObject:@"Location B" forKey:@"location"];

  NSMutableDictionary *opponent3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [opponent3 setObject:@"opponent C" forKey:@"name"];
  [opponent3 setObject:@"zz matches | zz wins || zz losts" forKey:@"stats"];
  [opponent3 setObject:@"Location C" forKey:@"location"];

  [opponents addObject:opponent];
  [opponents addObject:opponent2];
  [opponents addObject:opponent3];

  [_topponents reloadData];

}
```

and here my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"opponentcell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



UILabel *lopponentname = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lopponentstats = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *llocation = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
lopponentname.text = [[opponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
lopponentstats.text = [[opponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"stats"];
llocation.text = [[opponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"location"];


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my fault!

I used to write:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
```

but I should use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**with "forIndexPath"**

Comment: The difference, for the record, is that the former may return `nil` whereas the latter will create an object where appropriate. The latter is the more modern and recommended way to do things but all the people advocating a manual check were giving you a solution that would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the trouble is in the cell. Create UITableViewCell subclass.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"opponentcell";
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.lopponentname.text = [[opponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.lopponentstats.text = [[opponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"stats"];
cell.llocation.text = [[opponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"location"];
return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after initialisation of cell. For me works properly.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for condition when cell is nil..
Initially the cell is nil..
So the data is loading only after scrolling...
Add below lines of code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method after initializing cell.

```
if (cell == nil) 
  {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
```

Hope this fixes the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using custom cel and it looks you have trouble in "cellForRowAtIndexPath". If you using .xib, you may find it useful.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"opponentcell";    

CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in nibObjects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomTableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomTableViewCell *) currentObject;
            }
        }
        [cell initViewStyles];
    }
```